# How to make Nav.Link href work with gh-pages

Tags: github-pages, react-bootstrap

I am trying to learn react and after learning the basics, I followed some video online on how to create a webapp. Now everything is looking well on my local. But I want to publish it on github pages and so I installed gh-pages and followed the steps in : https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

So my page is up in https://alvincabayan.github.io/amc-webapp/, only problem is the links are not working.

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "amc-webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-particles-js": "^2.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "homepage": "http://alvincabayan.github.io/amc-webapp"
}
```

NavigationBar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles = styled.div`
  .navbar {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  a, .navbar-brand, .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #bbb;
    &:hover {
      color: white;
    }
  }
`;

export const NavigationBar = () => (
  <Styles>
    <Navbar expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">AMC</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
        <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </Styles >
)
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Home} from './components/Home';
import {About} from './components/About';
import {Contact} from './components/Contact';
import {NoMatch} from './components/NoMatch';
import {Layout} from './components/Layout';
import {NavigationBar} from './components/NavigationBar';
import {HomeJumbotron} from './components/HomeJumbotron';



function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <NavigationBar/>
        <HomeJumbotron/>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Shouldn't the codes:

```
<Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
```

point to:

```
https://alvincabayan.github.io/amc-webapp/
https://alvincabayan.github.io/amc-webapp/about
https://alvincabayan.github.io/amc-webapp/contact
```

I can see that the corresdponding js are loaded when I inspected the page but trying to show them by dragging them into the browser results in 404.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your routes's path you have to put the name of the repo.
As you can see, right now when you click on a Link the name of the repo disapear.

So you can do for home page :

```
 <Route exact path="amc-webapp/" component={Home} />
```

I had the same issue, posted on SO without answer. It might not be the best things to do but it works.

Comment: What I did is: <Route path="/amc-webapp/about" component={About} />
and on navigator: <Link to="/amc-webapp/about">About</Link>

and it works. Thanks for that.
Another thing I found out is that when I click the about button the link: https://alvincabayan.github.io/amc-webapp/about
will be displayed on URL.

but when I go to that URL via URL directly, it gives me 404. Why is that?

Comment: I thinks it's the way github works. May be you have to access the repo before navigating. I'm glad that it works for you. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

React router allows you to set a basename used for all routes. Just use this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/BrowserRouter.md#basename-string